# To prove extension of a holomorphic function to an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose  f  is holomorphic  in  an  open  neighbourhood  of  $p\in \mathbb {C}$.  Given that  the  series  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{f^{(n)} (p)}$  converges   absolutely, prove   that  $f$  can  be  extended  to  an  entire  function.

What I did: By  cauchy-taylor theorem $f (z) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty {f^{(n)} (p)(z-p)^n\over n!}$
Then I showed that  $\frac{1}{R}=\lim\frac {f^{(n+1)}(p) n!}{f^{(n)} (p) (n+1)!} =0 $, $R$ is radius of convergence. My  question is does the $\lim \frac {f^{(n+1)}(p)}{f^{(n)}(p)}$ exist? Otherwise  my proof is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

$f^{(n)} (p) \to 0$ so  $\{f^{(n)} (p)\}$ is a bounded sequence. So the series $\sum \frac {f^{(n)}(p) (z-p)^{n}} {n!}$ is dominated by a constant times the series for $e^{|z-p|}$ which converges for all $z$.

Comment: So you are saying that every function dominated by an entire function is entire...OK  I will try to prove this

Comment: That is not what I am saying. You can have a discontinuous function dominated by an entire function. What I am saying is that  a power series dominated by a series convergent for all $z$ represents an entire function.

Comment: Alright ..thank you

Comment: But actually then I know nothing about a  function dominated by another function...as you said a discontinuous function can be dominated by an entire function..I can not understand how ? So can you recommend me a book  from where I can study about the properties of a function ,dominated by another function.

Answer (score 1):

The series $$u_n=\cases{\frac1{n^2}& $n$ even\cr \frac1{n^3}& $n$ odd}$$
converges absolutely, yet the ratio $\frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}}$ has no limit, its $\limsup$ is $\infty$ and its $\liminf$ is $0$.

Comment: OK  then my proof is absolutely wrong. Can u tell me how to prove the above problem then?